# Understanding commutative cochain problem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

I have just read about commutative cochain problem(CCP) [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week288.html) and I'm trying understand it.

It states that you cannot turn(in nontrivial way) simplicial set $S$ to differential graded commutative algebra(DGCA) $\Lambda^*(S)$ which has the usual cohomology $H^*(S)$.

If I modify above problem slightly, is it still impossible?

Start wit simplicial complex $(S,\partial)$. Can we find finite chain complex $(T, \partial)$, such that $(S,\partial)\subset (T,\partial)$ and that we can turn $T$ into DGCA $(T,d,\wedge)$ such that $(S,d)$ is cochain subcomplex of $(T,d)$ and cohomolgy groups of $(S,d)$ are the same as of $(S,\partial)$?

Motivation: Sometimes it is useful to consider dual graph $S^*$ of $S$. As CCP states, it is impossible to construct graded commutative multiplication on cochains of $S$, but what if the product can mix chochains of $S$ and $S^*$?

---

edit: My main motivation is that I'm interested in discrete exterior calculus and I stumbled upon article [Theoretical Limitations of Discrete Exterior Calculus in the Context of Computational Electromagnetics](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4526921) where they say that CCP is a problem, so I would like to understand how big the problem is.

Comment: The topic interests me so I'd like to try to answer your question but I don't understand it. You say $S$ is a "simplicial complex", and I can't tell if you mean a simplicial chain complex, or an ordinary simplicial complex. Either way I don't know how it could be a subset of an ordinary chain complex. If I understand the question, if $X$ is any finite simplicial set (or simplicial complex converted into a simplicial set), then the ordinary simplicial cochains form a dga, degree-wise finitely generated, that computes the cohomology of $X$.

Comment: Ups, I have a little knowledge of the math in question, so I'm probably mixing up terminology. Ok, what is the difference between simplicial chain complex(scc) and simplicial complex(sc)? Is it that all simplices in scc have fixed orientation? Why is there a problem for simplicial chain complex to be subcomplex of another ordinary chain complex? Scc is an ordinary chain complex right? And yes, ordinary simplicial cochains form a dga, which is not graded-commutative but I'm looking for graded-commutative dga. I changed dga to dgca in the question to make it more clear.

Comment: A simplicial chain complex is a simplcial object in the category of chain complexes, i.e., a sequence of chain complexes $A_n$ with face and boundary maps satisfying certain relations. A simplicial complex is usually taken to mean a collection of subsets of a set, closed under certain set operations. I hope that makes it clear that it is not clear what you mean for a simplicial chain complex, or a simplicial complex to be a subset of a chain complex. It is possible to view a chain complex as a simplicial chain complex concentrated in degree zero, but I doubt that's what you have in mind.